# Efficient ways to initialize class members; both heap and stack allocated

Tags: c++, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Assume we have the following:

```
//! SomeClass.hpp
class 
{
public:
    SomeClass( void );

   ~SomeClass( void ) 
    { 
       delete mFoo; 
       delete mBar; 
    }
    ...

private:
    Foo* mFoo;
    Bar* mBar;
    StackObj mStackFoo;
};

//! SomeClass.cpp
SomeClass::SomeClass( void )
{
     mFoo = new Foo;
     mBar = new Bar; 
     mStackFoo = StackObj( ... );
}
```

Now, when we initialize the pointers, my understanding is that the constructor will [create unnecessary copies](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) of SomeClass' members, thus allocating **and then deallocating** memory simply for the sake of allocating memory.

---

It's common to use initializer lists, coupled with a separate initialization function (for heap allocated memory) as a method to avoid this. Say `SomeClass` has a private member function defined as `void initHeapMem( void )`. Then we can do,

```
SomeClass::SomeClass( void )
    : mFoo( NULL ),
      mBar( NULL ),
      mStackFoo( ... )
{
     initHeapMem();
}

void SomeClass::initHeapMem( void )
{
    mFoo = new Foo;
    mBar = new Bar;
}
```

Naturally, this *somewhat* fixes the problem. The issue here I believe is that there's still the overhead of another function call being performed.

The reason why we can't use initialization lists for raw pointers is because they're **not thread safe**. If something goes wrong, and the program throws an exception, there will still be a memory leak. **Note: this is according to what I've read, my apologies if this is wrong**.

---

So, with boost/C++11, we can use smart pointers from an `#include <tr1/memory>` directive in the header file ( assuming we're using STL ).

If we were to use, say, `std::unique_ptr< T >`, then we'd have `Bar* mBar` and `Foo* mFoo` replaced with:

```
std::unique_ptr< Foo > mFoo;
std::unique_ptr< Bar > mBar;
```

Which would then allow us to do,

```
SomeClass::SomeClass( void )
   mFoo( new Foo ),
   mBar( new Bar ),
   mStackFoo( ... )
{
}
```

Since the smart pointer effectively *wraps* the memory allocation in *its own* constructor.

While this is a nice solution, I personally am not one to use smart pointers for every heap object I create, and I know there are others in the C++ community who feel the same way.

---

### **tl;dr**

With all of that out of the way, what I'm really wondering is **if there are any more efficient alternatives to initializing class members within an object** (especially with the advent of C++11), apart from the ones I listed above.

Comment: Please expand on this comment: '... constructor will create unnecessary copies'

Comment: What do you actually (specifically) mean by "the constructor will create unnecessary copies of SomeClass' members"? Your very first example looks fine to me so I'm wondering if you're misunderstanding something about the nature of constructors.

Comment: These pointers you're using are fundamental scalers. They are default-constructed in your first example (which means absolutely nothing). Were they FCL's (like `mStackFoo`) they would have constructors etc, fire (which is exactly what your smart pointers utilize to make their job work). What "unnecessary copies" are you talking about regarding your object's default construction of two **pointers** (which you *can* value-initialize if you want to, and should do so)??

Comment: It seems to me that the question is predicated on the false statement '.. constructor will create unnecessary copies of SomeClass' members'. If you can clarify your current understanding it will be easier to identify what the misunderstanding is.

Comment: @mythagel, I added a hyperlink to the 'create unnecessary copies' sentence. Apologies for the misunderstanding, though I would certainly appreciate any clarification on this.

Comment: Why are you using `new` so much to begin with? If you're `new`ing everything then you're doing something wrong already...

Comment: Informally speaking, by the time the constructor body executes the members of the object must be initialised one way or the other. You have an option here, the compiler can do it for you and then you assign to those (initialised) variables in the body - or you can initialise the members directly (preferred).

Comment: (cont) In your example above, the _pointers_ mFoo and mBar are default initialized. Default initialisation for pointers is analogous to that for integers - the value is unspecified. Note that at this point no memory is allocated.

Comment: Now if the members of your class had non-trivial default constructors then executing those constructors before your objects' constructor body, only to then construct new temporary objects in the ctor body and copy assign them to the members would be wasteful - hence why the ctor initialiser list is preferred.

Comment: Either of the answers below give you a solution, but I hope this clarifies the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you do this?

```
SomeClass::SomeClass( void ) : 
mFoo(new Foo)
, mBar(new Bar)
{
}
```

They are raw pointers and no unnecessary copies are created.

I should also point out that the reason you use initializer lists is so that the object is in a valid state (that is, all members have valid values) when the constructor body is executed.

```
SomeClass::SomeClass( void )
{
     //before this point, mFoo and mBar's values are unpredictable
     mFoo = new Foo;
     mBar = new Bar;
}
```

Regarding exceptions, the destructor of SomeClass will not be called ONLY if the [exception is thrown inside the constructor itself](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/selfcleaning-members.html).

Finally, regarding being thread safe or not, it depends on whether each thread has its own copy of SomeClass or not and whether SomeClass contains static members that are being written to.

Comment: In what context are you referring to, exactly? Are the Foo and Bar members raw or smart pointers?

Answer (score 4):

`unique_ptr` is the right solution here. It has several advantages:

- It explicitly documents ownership. One of the issues with raw pointers is that they don’t indicate anything about who owns them. With `unique_ptr` you have a single owner, and must explicitly `move` ownership should you want to transfer it.
- It has essentially no overhead; the only thing `unique_ptr` does is invoke the deleter, which you were going to do anyway. Now you have the performance benefits of deterministic memory behaviour without the effort of manual memory management.
- It makes thread- and exception-safety much easier to attain, thanks to RAII. That means less fretting about instruction order, and less explicit cleanup code. You get the benefits of exceptions without all of the problems that caused them to be avoided in so much C++03 code.

`shared_ptr` is in my experience needed much less often than `unique_ptr`. Shared ownership is useful mainly when you have an immutable resource such as a texture or audio file, where loading and copying are both expensive, but which you want to unload when it’s not in use. `shared_ptr` also imposes the overhead of added safety (thread-safety in particular) and reference counting.

The disadvantage, of course, is that smart pointers impose a syntactic overhead. They are not as “native” as raw pointers. For that, you have `typedef`, `auto`, `decltype`, and rolling your own convenience functions such as `make_unique`.